# Unsafe deserialization from JSON

Tags: json, owasp-top-ten

Seeking any example of exploitable unsafe deserialiazation where the serialized format is json and not some binary format.

Even better would be an example where calling a Java constructor of an arbitrary class(in some common library) is sufficient to do something malicious, and not rely on vulnerable readResolve, readObject or such specific to Java Serialization.

Comment: I googled your title and got this as the top hit: https://www.owasp.org/images/d/d7/Marshaller_Deserialization_Attacks.pdf.pdf

Comment: Any specific reason you mention Java? JSON deserialization libraries are available for all major languages, and languages like C (with no variable-length string type) are naturally more vulnerable.

Comment: This is embarrassing, I obviously googled a bit, but only when writing the question did a formalize better what I was looking for, mostly I wanted to refute claim that the issue is only with binary formats like Java serialization and python pickles. At a glance the link answers at least my first part, but using setters and not using non default constructors as in my second part.

Comment: Is not clear what you asking for, looks like a programing question more than security question